# How can I enable tools and functions auto-hide in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I cleaned my touch-pad yesterday I accidentally clicked on something.  After that I was still in normal screen. But the left tool-bar and the right function-section was gone, like in full-screen mode.

But it was — not — full-screen.

So, I figured I could hover over the left border of the screen. And the tool-bar came back to view. Likewise the functions on right side. That was actually pretty cool. Because you now have an undisturbed view on the art.

But I was not sure how I did it.

I found that if i chose `Window > Workplace > Essentials` then the bars came back. Now I want the auto-hiding back. I could not find an explanation on the web as to how to do this.

How do you enter the mode described above?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Danielillo's answer....

<kbd>Tab</kbd> will hide all panels, including the toolbar, while *not* entering full screen mode.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will hide all panels *except* the tool bar, while *not* switching to full screen mode.

Comment: That was — not — what I experienced. Also I doubt you made my question more readable. [It was based on Easy-to-Read rules.](http://easy-to-read.eu/)

Comment: @AjAX. yes but you are also misusing the question area by editing the answer into it

Comment: @joojaa this user appears to merely be argumentative in all instances. I wouldn't put too much effort here `:)`

Comment: no idea what all the babbling is about, but these shortcuts have helped me restore the menu's again when I was alt tabbing around. Thanks, vote up!

Answer (score 1):

It's the same shortcut as Photoshop:

Pressing the key **F** once > hide the window frame

Pressing the key **F** twice > hide everything and get full screen artboard

Comment: Thanks for answering. It was — not — full screen though. It was usual work-place.

Answer (score -1):

It is simple.

When pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> it enters this mode.

Then you can hover over the edge of the screen.

And the panels reappear while hovering.

[Taken from here.](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2492696)

Comment: Instead of answering with what is essentially a copy of Scott's answer press the check mark next to the answer that addresses this.

Comment: He did — not — address the hovering. Which was explicitly aksed. And it was written in my question already. @joojaa

Comment: Well even so he did say that tab does this. So if you disagree with it you need to explain why this is different

Comment: Anyway i feel that "When pressing Tab it enters this mode" is hard to parse maybe you would want to be proper and write "pressing tab enters this mode" for example. So proper wording becomes even more important if you enforce  Easy to read rules.